# Using vault in Ansible gives: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode'

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I'm trying to use `debops.nullmailer` on Ansible (2.4) to configure nullmailer on my hosts. I want to keep the password encrypted in the variable, so am looking to use the vault functionality to encrypt the secret. My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- name: My baseline
  hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    nullmailer__default_remotes:
     - port: "587"
       host: smtp.mailgun.org
       user: myusername
       pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          6430...63433
  roles:
    - role: debops.nullmailer
```

However, applying this with `--ask-vault-pass` gives a long-winded error:

> TASK [debops.nullmailer : Generate private configuration files] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   fatal: [talkbot]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "[{u'dest': u'/etc/nullmailer/remotes', u'content': u\"{{ lookup('template', 'lookup/nullmailer__remotes.j2') | from_yaml | join('\n') }}\", u'group': u'mail', u'mode': u'0600', u'owner': u'mail'}]: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'template'. Error was a , original message: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% set nullmailer__tpl_remotes = [] %}\n{% for entry in (nullmailer__default_remotes + nullmailer__remotes) %}\n{%   set nullmailer__tpl_entry = [] %}\n{%   if entry is string %}\n{%     set _ = nullmailer__tpl_remotes.append(entry) %}\n{%   elif entry is mapping %}\n{%     if entry.host|d() %}\n{%       set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append(entry.host) %}\n{%       set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append(entry.protocol|d('smtp')) %}\n{%       if (((entry.starttls|d() and entry.starttls|bool) or nullmailer__starttls|bool) and (entry.ssl is undefined or not entry.ssl|bool) and (entry.options is undefined or not entry.options)) %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--starttls') %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.ssl|d() and entry.ssl|bool %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--ssl') %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.insecure|d() and entry.insecure|bool %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--insecure') %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.x509fmtder|d() and entry.x509fmtder|bool %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--x509fmtder') %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.x509cafile|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--x509cafile=' + entry.x509cafile) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.x509certfile|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--x509certfile=' + entry.x509certfile) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.x509crlfile|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--x509crlfile=' + entry.x509crlfile) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.port|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--port=' + entry.port) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if ((entry.auth|d() and entry.auth|bool) or (entry.auth_login|d() and entry.auth_login|bool)) %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--auth-login') %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.user|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--user=' + entry.user) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.password|d() or entry.pass|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append('--pass=' + (entry.password | d(entry.pass))) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       if entry.options|d() %}\n{%         set _ = nullmailer__tpl_entry.append(entry.options if entry.options is string else entry.options|join(' ')) %}\n{%       endif %}\n{%       set _ = nullmailer__tpl_remotes.append(nullmailer__tpl_entry | join(' ')) %}\n{%     endif %}\n{%   endif %}\n{% endfor %}\n{% if nullmailer__tpl_remotes %}\n{%   for entry in nullmailer__tpl_remotes %}\n- '{{ entry }}'\n{%   endfor %}\n{% else %}\n- ''\n{% endif %}\n): cannot concatenate 'str' and 'AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode' objects"}

Taking out the `pass` variable causes it to work successfully, but obviously without the `--pass=` parameter in `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` needed.

I'm pretty new to ansible - what's going on here? Why is it trying to concatenate a `str` and an `AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode`? Is the decryption not working?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the decryption not working?

It’s not even attempted when an Ansible Vault-encrypted variable is used inside Jinja2 (Python) `append` method.

That said, most likely you should:

- use an Ansible Vault file instead of a variable, or
- file an issue on GitHub / fix [`ansible-nullmailer`](https://github.com/debops/ansible-nullmailer) project yourself to handle the situation.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I will attempt using a vault file instead.